# Codeception select option

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, codeception

I am using codeception to try and click , selection Option within my the form. The issue is that, when I try to check the checkbox, it selects the privacy info href link, opposed to checkbox which I want it to select.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="myclass">
    <div class="mb">
      <label class=" custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="from_accept" name="fform[accept]" class="custom-checkbox__input" value="1">
 <span class="custom-checkbox__text">
         ::before
          "I agree to terms "
    <a href="[there is a link here]">terms and conditions</a> 
          "and some more text here "
     <a href="[there is a link here]">privacy info</a>
         "."
        ::after
 </span>
     </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried Xpath & CSS selectors but with no luck, even the hover shows me that it see's just the last href anchor link.

Comment: Can you show us your work please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Try the following `xpath`:

```
//div[@class='row']/div[@class='myclass']/div[@class='mb']/label[@class=' custom-checkbox' and @class='custom-checkbox__input']//self::label
```

> Note that there is a blank (i.e. a space) within `class=" custom-checkbox"`

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, It's close but it continues to select the last anchor tag ... ?

Comment: Also I modified the code .. as there are some ::before ::after ... lines in there. Don't know if this makes a difference ?

Comment: @toddy As per the updated HTML it will be a bit tricky to achieve the desired step. In case the URL is a public URL can you share it with us?
 In the mean time check my updated Answer and let me know the status. Thanks

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Sadly it doesn't work and still clicks the last "a" tag ... At the moment I can't share the URL. I will keep trying. It's proven very tricky. Thanks again :)